# How to remove svn url from commit messages?

Tags: git, github, git-svn

I'm trying to push a git-svn repo to github but I don't want the url to appear in my commit messages.

They appear because I'm developing with svn and only using git-svn to push to github. So all my messages looks like:

```
Some changes

git-svn-id: ........
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could turn it off by setting the following config options (globally or per remote basis), but it is highly recommended **NOT** to do so, since `git svn` would be unable to fetch without this metadata.

```
svn.noMetadata = true
svn-remote.origin.noMetadata = true
```

You could also use the `--no-metadata` option with `git svn clone` to achieve the same result.

From the man page of [`git-svn`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html):

> **--no-metadata**
>
> Set the noMetadata option in the [svn-remote] config. This option is not recommended, please read the svn.noMetadata section
>   of this manpage before using this option.

And the related config file options:

> **svn.noMetadata**
>
> **svn-remote..noMetadata**
>
> This gets rid of the
>   git-svn-id: lines at the end of every commit.
>
> This option can only be used for one-shot imports as git svn will not
>   be able to fetch again without metadata. Additionally, if you lose
>   your .git/svn/*/.rev_map. files, git svn will not be able to rebuild
>   them.
>
> The git svn log command will not work on repositories using this,
>   either. Using this conflicts with the useSvmProps option for
>   (hopefully) obvious reasons.
>
> This option is NOT recommended as it makes it difficult to track down
>   old references to SVN revision numbers in existing documentation, bug
>   reports and archives. If you plan to eventually migrate from SVN to
>   git and are certain about dropping SVN history, consider
>   git-filter-branch(1) instead. filter-branch also allows reformatting
>   of metadata for ease-of-reading and rewriting authorship info for
>   non-"svn.authorsFile" users.

Answer (score 8):

Just in case you already fetched the data using the `git svn fetch` you may use `git filter-branch` as an alternative.

```
git filter-branch -f --msg-filter 'sed -e "/git-svn-id:/d" -e "/Former-commit-id:/d"'
```

You can change the "git-svn-id:" or "Former-commit-id:" accordingly.